# Wrap the message if it's too long in a mat expansion panel

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to wrap an XML message in a mat-expansion-panel if it's too long so it continues down instead of going beyond the panel.

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="panel">
  <pre>{{pretty(message.content)}}</pre>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

```
.panel {
  max-height: 80vh;
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```
pretty(message: string) {
  return vkbeautify.xml(message);
}
```

I've tried using `white-space`, `word-break`, wrapping the message in `<p>` tag and setting the width to 85% but all these things didn't seem to do anything.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkfiw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target to `pre` tag

```
.panel pre {
  max-height: 80vh;
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```